# What is a collective term for castles, citadels, forts, palaces etc.?

Tags: collective-nouns

We at [Travel-SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) are having an ongoing tag reorganization, and we're trying to find a collective term that encompasses the following:

- castles
- châteaux (which are really castles, but not every castle is a château)
- palaces
- forts
- citadels
- [country houses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47763/english-country-houses) (which are really palaces, but for non-royals)

We'd appreciate if you guys can come up with an appropriate category that covers these all. We don't want to create separate tags because frankly people won't know the difference between these and won't care.

We were thinking of `fortified-structures` or `palatial-structures`, but these don't work quite well. `residences` is just too broad, and `royal-residences` is not correct since country houses were not used by royal figures.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the age defining to the term as well? Something along the line of *historical* ...

Comment: *landmarks*, maybe

Comment: @Autoresponder: `landmarks` is so broad that it can cover anything. Not very useful for our purposes, we're looking for more narrow tag.

Comment: I think `landmarks` is great. I don't think we have to worry about being too broad. Maybe if we had hundreds of such questions that clearly seemed to fall into different subtypes. But at this stage that's not the case.

Comment: What about *castles-etc.*?

Comment: *Heritage Buildings.* Or *Heritage Houses*. *Royal Residences*. *Home & Castle*.

Comment: *Unreal Estate/Imperial Bricks* :-)

Comment: If `palatial-structures` and `royal-residences` are close to what's needed, perhaps `palatial-residences` will work?

Comment: @onomatomaniak, you should put "castles-etc" in an answer so we can vote it up.

Comment: Question...are the palaces and country houses to which you refer primarily those that resemble castles? In other words, if a noble built a country house that was more like a very large house and less like a small-scale castle, would it qualify?

Comment: @jprete: When I said "country house" I kind of meant "a (possibly smallish) palace in the country", like [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5uouH.jpg). So yeah, I guess sufficiently large houses would qualify.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Added. :)

Comment: Sounds like you have an edifice complex.

Comment: would you take e.g. cathedrals into account (or other possibly all religoius, aristocratic and military monuments)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After looking at wikipedia entries for castles and fortifications, I can see that there are many technical historical-architectural terms which are very precise and detailed.

**1<sup>st</sup> option**
The encompassing term might be **[fortifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortification)**. This is technically probably a bit wide as it would include military constructs which people do not inhabit and might (technically) miss some of the buildings you are trying to describe. (You might go with *fortified historical residences* or some such term)

**2<sup>nd</sup> option**
On the other hand, depending on technical correctness you are aiming for, pragmatically and simply **castles** might be a good tag (you can explain in the tags summary that it also includes *citadels*, *stately homes*, [etc..](http://www.castlesandmanorhouses.com/types.htm) )

Both the term **castle** and **fortification** are taken from this paragraph in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle#Use_of_the_term):

> **Castle** is sometimes used as a catch-all term for all kinds of **fortifications**, and as a result has been misapplied in the technical sense. An example of this is Maiden Castle which, despite the name, is an Iron Age hill fort, which had a very different origin and purpose. Although "castle" has not become, like *chateau* in French and *schloss* in German, a generic term for an English country house, many of these use the word in their name while having few if any of the architectural characteristics...

**3<sup>rd</sup> option**

Combining common characteristics of the terms that you want to describe

- *Historical private residences* (is it really necessary to say private, I wonder)
- *Historical or fortified residences*

Finally, I am not a historian nor an architect, so maybe asking in a more specialized environment might yield technically more appropriate result (wikipedia discussion page?).

Comment: +1 for *fortified residences* I think it captures the general style of the buildings the OP mentions plus the common aspect of their intended purpose, which is to house people.

Comment: @Kitḫ, that was the idea, only issue is that *palaces* and *country houses* are not necessarily fortified.

Comment: I think most people who are not well-versed in buildings of this sort think of all of them as "castles" (option 2 here).

Comment: This looks a lot like what I would have answered (+1). I think of the given options, I'd probably go with `castles` for a tag just for the sake of brevity. Someone going on a "castle tour" probably wouldn't be too horribly bummed or surprised to hit a country house or two. You can of course explain the tag's intended coverage in its FAQ.

Comment: @Kith - A palace is necessarily NOT fortified.  If it was, it would be a castle.

Comment: @chris, "Palaces in East Asia, such as the imperial palaces of Korea, Thailand, Vietnam, Japan and China's Forbidden City, consist of many low pavilions surrounded by vast, *walled gardens*, in contrast to the single building palaces of Medieval Western Europe." Although not heavily fortified those walls and gardens sometimes contained a small army. Although in principle I agree with you.

Comment: Of these, definitely `castles` for a tag.

Comment: I really like `historical-residences`, as it definitely includes palaces, etc.  However, if it was being applied to some kind of fortified structure, I'd definitely tag the question `castles` as well, since castles are awesome.

Answer (score 9):

Does "Stately homes and castles" cover it? Or even just "Stately homes"?

Comment: +1: I think this encompasses it all pretty nicely, avoiding the odd connotations of some suggestions above

Answer (score 8):

These tend to be referred to as *historic buildings* or sometimes the broader term *ancient monuments*. Of course those terms aren't precisely what you're looking for, since both terms can include buildings not on your list - an ancient barn, full of history, could be counted as an historic building or ancient monument - and equally if a palace was built right now it wouldn't be counted as either term (although it would, as Barrie points out, most likely be *of architectural interest*).

In Britain, the terms *historic building* and *ancient monument* have legal implications:

[Historical buildings are](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aMgqEsuj_GK4J%3aenglish.cca.gov.tw/public/Attachment/411317323871.pdf%20historic%20buildings%20definition&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESi0qpdEhRilhWtw-8il9A5G47M0BKMam-fs9LywP9n8c2omn1EqdMoO3fuwKIktNuCA6_YMTID4L2vFztN3dum5lO6fUlBy8Oq42AXA5iHGZmZb7aghJ0caIDB_fQxJ_Y6vGae9&sig=AHIEtbSBRkCsmSYMHm-3J3M7g7TvvpoxuQ):

> ancient buildings, traditional settlements, old towns and streets and
>   other historical and cultural remains that contain historical and
>   cultural values, but have yet to be designated as ancient monuments.

[Ancient monuments are](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1979/46):

> either [Scheduled Ancient Monuments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduled_Ancient_Monument) or "any other monument
>   which in the opinion of the Secretary of State is of public interest
>   by reason of the historic, architectural, traditional, artistic or
>   archaeological interest attaching to it"

Perhaps something like *historical residences* fits the bill?

Comment: There's a castle in Tullamore which I wouldn't think of as an ancient monument. It dates from the 1790s, which is hardly "ancient". An ancient monument is something like Newgrange.

Answer (score 7):

How about *castles-etc.*? It strikes me as unambiguous and simple.

Comment: +1 It's ambiguous in that anything could be in the etc., but the official list should be clearly shown in the tag wiki.

Comment: While I think I'd still lean toward just plain `castles`, this is worth consideration because it doesn't add *too* much length, while providing a bit of protection against misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

The collective term that encompasses ALL of these may actually be the word `hold`. Military fortifications are `strongholds` and residential palaces are `households` (a term that has been watered down as living standards increased for the average family). The word household means the hold (base/estate/whatever) of a house (as in family*).

At least that's what a few minutes of googling produced.

`*` "the Johnson family" could be written as "the house of Johnson", just to help anyone who don't know the "old" way of saying things. `house (n) Meaning "family, including ancestors and descendants, especially if noble" is from c.1000.` [source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=house)

Answer (score 2):

They are all - are they not? - *buildings of historical and architectural interest*?

Comment: Yeah, that's not bad, but I was hoping for something a bit shorter.. `buildings-of-historical-and-architectural-interest` is hardly a good tag name.

Comment: Plus, it would also cover cathedrals and churches, and we want to keep them separate.

Comment: 'Secular monuments'? One of the OED's definitions of 'monument' is 'A structure, edifice, or (in later use also) site of historical interest or importance.'

Comment: I don't think it's ultra important to distinguish cathedrals and churches at this level. We have five tag slots so we could have both tags and some people would use one or the other and some use both.

Comment: @jwpat7: Thanks, now corrected. (If it's any excuse, I'm having to type with one hand bandaged at the moment.)

Comment: Yes, they are. However, so is the Leaning Tower of Pisa, which does not fall under the category.

Answer (score 2):

Other than "buildings", I don't see what these have in common. Castles, forts, and citadels would all be fortifications, but "palaces" and "country houses" certainly would not. Most of your list are big, impressive structures, but again, "country houses" and "chateaux" are not.

The only connection I see is that they are all buildings that you consider interesting. Maybe something like "picturesque buildings"? Possibly "historic buildings" if that's what you're driving at.

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering if perhaps dogged determination to include all of those structures in one tag is a bit of a stretch.  In particular, as some have commented, *castle* implies fortification while *palace* tends to imply size or opulence without much emphasis on fortification.

Further, even when cities or large structures in Asia are fortified, they tend to be referred to as *palaces* anyway, rather than *castles*.  Personally, I would find it weird to tag the Forbidden City under *castles*.

Therefore, my recommendation would be to have two separate tags, `castles` and `palaces`, even though they overlap and will often be used together.

Answer (score 1):

**Stately Structures**

Some of the other answers are good, but I believe this is the catchiest which makes it good for a tag. Just look at it...

`stately-structures`

Damn, that's nice.